# How to use a scanner for input for a Reverse Polish Notation Calculator?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a reverse polish notation calculator.
The problem is I don't know how to distinguish between the different data types of the operator and operand. Is there a way I can use the scanner to run a different method depending on whether the input is a char or a integer. I'm doing this in java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Scanner.hasNextInt():

```
Scanner s=new Scanner();
if(s.hasNextInt()) {
   //read integer from input:
   int num = s.nextInt();
   // process num
} else {
   //read string/char from input:
   String str = s.next();
   // process str
}
```